# Why is mount mounting the directory to /dev/loop0 instead of the device? Can't write all my files to the directory as a result (since it's too small)

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi, sd-card, loop-device

I want to write about 38 MB of files to a partition that is 100 MB large. However, when I mount that partition to the directory, it mounts to `/dev/loop0` instead of `/dev/sdc1`  (in my example).

This seems to be a problem as the `mv` command won't let me write all 38 MB of files to the device now. Below is everything I did (following for my use case, but not sure if this is relevant [Raspberry Pi 3](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3)):

```
[slife pi]# fdisk /dev/sdc

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): o
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x2ec21fb4.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 29.83 GiB, 32010928128 bytes, 62521344 sectors
Disk model: Card  Reader
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2ec21fb4

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-62521343, default 2048):
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-62521343, default 62521343): +100M

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 100 MiB.

Command (m for help): t
Selected partition 1
Hex code (type L to list all codes): c
Changed type of partition 'Linux' to 'W95 FAT32 (LBA)'.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (2-4, default 2): 2
First sector (206848-62521343, default 206848):
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (206848-62521343, default 62521343):

Created a new partition 2 of type 'Linux' and of size 29.7 GiB.
Partition #2 contains a ext4 signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: y

The signature will be removed by a write command.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.

[slife pi]# mkfs.vfat /dev/sdc1
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
[slife pi]# ls
ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar.gz  ArchLinuxARM-rpi-latest.tar.gz.1  boot  root  unzipped
[slife pi]# mount /dev/sdc1 boot
[slife pi]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    10M  0 loop /mnt/pi/boot
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   260M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0   1.3T  0 part
├─sda4   8:4    0   873M  0 part
├─sda5   8:5    0    16G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0   512M  0 part /boot/EFI
└─sda7   8:7    0 570.2G  0 part /
sdc      8:32   1  29.8G  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   1   100M  0 part
└─sdc2   8:34   1  29.7G  0 part
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
[slife pi]# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc2
mke2fs 1.45.4 (23-Sep-2019)
Creating filesystem with 7789312 4k blocks and 1949696 inodes
Filesystem UUID: e4033af0-dd50-4286-abc4-ea6982b21439
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
    4096000

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

[slife pi]# mount /dev/sdc2 root
[slife pi]# bsdtar -xpf ArchLinuxARM-rpi-2-latest.tar.gz -C root
[slife pi]# sync
[slife pi]# mv root/boot/* boot
mv: error writing 'boot/kernel7.img': No space left on device
mv: cannot create directory 'boot/overlays': No space left on device
mv: error writing 'boot/start4cd.elf': No space left on device
mv: error writing 'boot/start4db.elf': No space left on device
mv: error writing 'boot/start4.elf': No space left on device
mv: error writing 'boot/start4x.elf': No space left on device
mv: error writing 'boot/start_cd.elf': No space left on device
mv: error writing 'boot/start_db.elf': No space left on device
mv: error writing 'boot/start.elf': No space left on device
mv: error writing 'boot/start_x.elf': No space left on device
```

As you can see, after the `mount /dev/sdc1 boot` command, it mounted `/dev/loop0` instead of `/dev/sdc1`. As a result, when I did `mv root/boot/* boot`, it returned `No space left on device` for a bunch of the files.

So how can I properly move these files to `/dev/sdc1`?

Here's a `du` call on `root/boot` just to show the directory size (I unzipped the contents locally to a directory called "unzipped" just for reference):

```
[slife unzipped]# du boot
940 boot/overlays
38776   boot
[slife unzipped]# du -h boot
940K    boot/overlays
38M boot
```

EDIT (to clarify the full paths): I'm trying to mount:
 `/dev/sdc1` to `/mnt/pi/boot` 
and 
`/dev/sdc2` to `/mnt/pi/root` (this one is successful).

EDIT 2:
Output of  `df -i /dev/sdc1`

```
Filesystem      Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
dev            2024406   546 2023860    1% /dev
```

EDIT 3: 
Output of the commands @telcoM asked for:

```
slife: ~ » losetup -l -a
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE DIO LOG-SEC
/dev/loop0         0      0         1  0 /dev/sdc1   0     512
slife: ~ » ls -l /dev/sdc1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10485760 Dec 30 12:49 /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: `df -i /dev/sdc1`

Comment: @IporSircer I posted the output in an edit

Comment: @fpmurphy what would mounting sdc2 to the entire /mnt directory do?

Comment: What is the output of `losetup -l -a`? And `ls -l /dev/sdc1` to confirm it is a real device and not accidentally been replaced with a regular 10M-sized file?

Comment: @telcoM added an edit with the output of those commands

Comment: If `/dev/sdc1` was a block device, you'd see a `b` at the beginning (e.g. `brw-r--r--`). So this is a normal file, not a block device. Now the question is how this happened...

Answer (score 3):

Your `/dev/sdc1` device node has been replaced with a regular file of 10M size, and it is now acting as a 10M partition image file. This is probably a result of an earlier mistake with some command.

First, unmount the file:

```
umount /mnt/pi/boot
losetup -l -a
## if the output of the losetup command above is not empty, run this command:
losetup -r /dev/loop0
```

Then, move the image file aside:

```
mv /dev/sdc1 /tmp/sdc1-image-10M.ima
```

(You probably don't have any use for this file, so you might just delete it instead, but better safe than sorry...)

Replace it with an actual block device node, as it should be, and set permissions.
This is one of the very few reasons to use the `mknod` command in modern systems:

```
mknod /dev/sdc1 b 8 33
chown root:disk /dev/sdc1
chmod 660 /dev/sdc1
```

The parameters for the mknod command are:

- name of the device to create
- type of the device: `b` = block device, `c` = character device.
- major device number: from your `lsblk` output for `sdc1`
- minor device number: also from your `lsblk` output for `sdc1`

Now, accessing `/dev/sdc1` should again get you the actual partition instead of the accidental image file. Since the original `mkfs.vfat` command affected the image file instead of the actual partition, you should do it again:

```
mkfs.vfat /dev/sdc1
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/pi/boot
```

and then you should be able to proceed with:

```
mv /mnt/pi/root/boot/* /mnt/pi/boot
```

(I'm using full paths for clarity; you can of course use shorter paths relative to your current directory if you wish.)

Comment: Or simply `sudo rm /dev/sdc1 && reboot` and then
`mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/pi/boot`

Answer (score 0):

Like @telecoM said, `/dev/sdc1` is a regular file that is 10MB large instead of a  by device node. Because device nodes are automatically generated `udev`, you can simply:

1. Remove `/dev/sdc1`: `sudo rm /dev/sdc1`
2. Remove the SD card / thumb drive
3. Insert the SD card / thumb drive